# How to automatically start fish shell in private mode?

Tags: fish

Thanks to the developers of Fish for making it possible to launch the shell in private mode :)

However, what am I supposed to add or change in the files fish_prompt.fish and/or config.fish in order to launch fish in private mode *automatically* when I open a new terminal window?

And if it is possible to launch fish in private mode automatically, is it possible afterwards to launch fish in *public* mode manually whenever it is necessary?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Private mode" is a commandline option to fish.

Instead of launching `fish`, start `fish --private`.

If you want to disable history after you have started fish, set the $fish_history variable to an empty value, i.e. `set -g fish_history ""`. This can also be done in config.fish.

Comment: Well, when I tried to add `fish --private` into the last line of config.fish at first and then into fish_prompt.fish, the shell stopped working both times. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you are doing wrong is that that starts a _new_ fish, that then reads the config, which starts another _new_ fish, which reads the config.... It's an infinite loop! Either `set -g fish_history ""`, or set your terminal to start `fish --private`, or start `fish --private` manually whenever you want it.

Comment: Thank you for clarification! I figured out now how it's supposed to be done with Mac OS X Terminal.